# ncurses program using MinGW-w64 fails with "Error opening terminal: xterm"

Tags: c++, mingw, ncurses, terminfo

I am trying to write a very simple ncurses program, just to play around with, using mingw-w64 on Windows 10. I installed the `mingw-w64-x86_64-ncurses` package with pacman, and am using the MSYS2 MinGW64 environment terminal. I have no experience with any curses library and very little experience in general developing software on Windows.

I have written the following hello world program in `Main.cpp`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ncurses.h>
#include "Headers.hpp"

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    initscr();
    printw("Hello World!");
    refresh();
    getch();
    endwin();
    return 0;
}
```

I compile this with the following command:

```
g++ -I /C/msys64/mingw64/include/ncurses HelloWorld.cpp -L/C/msys64/mingw64/bin -lncursesw6 -o main
```

It compiles, but when I run `main.exe`, I get

```
Error opening terminal: xterm.
```

Why does this happen, and how can I fix it?

Comment: I can reproduce, but it works if I run the program in `cmd`. Probably `mintty` doesn't count as a true interactive console for this library.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Somehow the `TERM` env var needs to be *unset* for the mingw build to work. On the contrary, the `TERM` env var needs to be *set* for the msys build to work. Not sure what's the rationale behind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The MInGW build works for Windows console (see [README.MinGW](https://github.com/ThomasDickey/ncurses-snapshots/blob/master/README.MinGW)).  Other platforms use `$TERM`.  msys2's mingw32 and mingw64 configurations are used for targeting the Windows console.  Use the msys2 configuration if you want a program to work in **that** configuration.

The Windows Console API uses function-calls rather than writing characters (and escape sequences).  This is different from mintty (used in msys2), xterm, Windows Terminal.

Further reading:

- [Using the Console](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/using-the-console)
- [Console Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-functions) (Windows Console API)

Comment: This is very clarifying, thank you. Like you said, it works on the Windows console. However, when I try to run the program while SSH-ing from a remote computer, also using the Windows console, I face the same issue from the original question, even when using the `ssh -t` option. Is there something different about running it like this?

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem using the ucrt64 environment on msys2. Seems the proper configuration for xterm can not be found. Try:

```
export TERM=xterm
export TERMINFO=<path_to_ncurse_build>/share/terminfo
./my_program.exe
```

It should work. Have good coding!!!

Comment: Yes this did work, see my example in an other answer.

Answer (score 0):

This [answer (on this page)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75368581/3219553) somewhat worked for me. Here are the example commands that I have given:

```
export TERM=xterm

export TERMINFO=/mingw64/share/terminfo
```

Then executed my program with: `./hello.exe`

However "MSYS2 MinGW x64" terminal did not work that well.
So I tried the Windows Command Prompt (Windows 11) and that worked very well.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ export TERMINFO=`ncursesw6-config --terminfo`
```